# Compare one array with an 2 dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

`a = [1,2,3];`

`b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];`

Why is that in javascript `a== b[0]` **return false**?

Thank you

Comment: Because JS compares objects not by values, but by references. If you used http://google.com with "javascript compare arrays" query you would find a lot of useful info

Comment: Consider that `[] == []` also returns `false`, because the arrays are different objects. There are plenty of ways to implement an array/object comparison function, you can use google for that. You could just use underscore and its [`_.isEqual()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript. Really good answer.

Comment: @Yogesh: which one? Your link points to a question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/933132. This one.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript objects are compared by references.

That said: a references to objects are compared, not the objects' contents.

Thus, One object `{}` will never be equal to another `{}` even though their contents are equal.

```
var a = {},
    b = {}; // not equal
```

Whereas if you create a variable by assigning another reference to it like:

```
var a = {},
    b = a; // equal
```

then both variables would hold the same reference and would be equal.